# How to pass data from one activity to another in Android

Tags: android

This is my first activity called CreateMessageActivity, were the user is ask to check the ckeckboxes so that it can calculate the total.

```
  public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    double fish1 = 0;
    double chicken1 = 0;
    double steak1 = 0;
    double total;
    String total1;

    CheckBox fish = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkFish);
    CheckBox chicken = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkChicken);
    CheckBox steak = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkSteak);

    //switch (view.getId()) {
       // case R.id.checkFish:
            if (fish.isChecked()) {
                fish1 = 5;

            } else {
                fish1 = 0;
            }
           // break;
       // case R.id.checkChicken:
            if (chicken.isChecked()) {
                chicken1 = 2;

            } else {
                chicken1 = 0;
            }
            // R.id.checkSteak:
            if (steak.isChecked()) {
                steak1 = 10;
            } else {
                steak1 = 0;
            }
            //break;
   // }
    total = fish1 + chicken1 + steak1;
    total1 = Double.toString(total);
    i need to pass total1 to the other activity call ReceiveMessageActivity.
    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateMessageActivity.this, ReceiveMessageActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", total1);               
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is my second activity that has to display the total in the textview.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_message);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView TXT = new TextView(this);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String status = bundle.getString("message");
    TXT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewactivity2);
    TXT.setText(status);
```

Comment: use getIntent().getStringExtra("message"))

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: try to replace total1 = Double.toString(total) by String.valueOf(total)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the error here? Did you try debugging the code? What the value of `total1` when you call the second activity? Please add details of your problem

Comment: Can you post your layout code?

Answer (score -1):

Method `getExtras()` returns a bundle, but you need to fetch a String.
Try this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_message);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Fetch message
    String status = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    TXT = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewactivity2);
    TXT.setText(status);
```

Comment: Error:(27, 51) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Bundle

Comment: Oops! I'm really sorry about that. Edited now.

Comment: What's the difference here? Your code is same as the code in question

Comment: The difference is the solution. Check the line below the //Fetch message comment.

Comment: Your method is the short hand method of what the user already tried